# Swift: How to do segue from UITableViewCell, Action sheet

Tags: swift, tableview

How to make a segue from UITableViewCell?
I have an action sheet, and a "modify profile" option, I want to make a segue to another viewController by passing an Object that is of type User.
Here is my code:

```
    let actionsheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Programmer un RDV", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.gotoCalendar()//Ouvrir la calendar
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Liste des RDV", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Factures", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Envoyer un Whatsapp", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Envoyer un SMS", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Modifier", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        //Ir i want to do segue to an other viewController, and pass data object
    }))
    actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Supprimer", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.deleteUser(); //Suppression du customer
    }))

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
    cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")

    actionsheet.addAction(cancelAction)
    myVC?.present(actionsheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell :

Step Create Protocol :
Add this code outside of class `NewTableViewCell`

```
protocol NewTableViewCellDelegate {
    // Indicates that the profile view option selected 
    func showProfileView(cellView : NewTableViewCell)
}
```

Add delegate variable in `NewTableViewCell`

```
var delegate: NewTableViewCellDelegate?
```

Then in action sheet :

```
actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Modifier", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
       delegate!.showProfileView(cellView: self)
}))
```

Now confirm UITableViewCell protocol in controller file by inheriting UITableViewCell with protocols.
like :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NewTableViewCellDelegate {

    func showProfileView(cellView : NewTableViewCell)
   {
        // push new view controller in stack 
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileViewController") as profileViewController
       vc.profileDate = profileDate
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variable in the `profileViewController` like `profileDate` and then after actionsheet option selected pass assign data to the variable.

```
actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Modifier", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // push new view controller in stack 
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileViewController") as profileViewController
    vc.profileDate = profileDate
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}))
```

Or

```
actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Modifier", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // Move to next view controller without stack
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
    vc.profileDate = profileDate
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
```

Or Using performSegue

```
actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Modifier", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileSegue", sender: self)

}))
```

Next :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profileSegue" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ProfileViewController {
                destinationVC.profileDate  = "Example"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an Error: Type 'UINavigationController?' has no member 'pushViewController'

Comment: Check out Update

Comment: UIViewController uses navigationController to push new view controller

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) in this line there is error: Value of type 'UserTableViewCell' has no member 'navigationController'

Comment: Im in UITableViewCell

Comment: UITableViewCell can not communicate with View for this connection its require Controller. add action sheet in controller. OR you can use protocol method.

Comment: I want it in the UITableViewCell, it is to have a better organization and a clearer code. How to do with protocols?